# phpmyadmin 'not privileged to view users' as root

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, root

I have recently installed MySQL and phpmyadmin on my Mac OSX Yosemite and enabled PHP and Apache. When I log into `localhost/phpmyadmin` as root, and with a password I am able to log in fine however when clicking on the users tab there is a message saying I do not have the privileges to view the users, I found this odd because I was logged in as root user, and on top of that it also still shows me the ability to create a new user. Is there something I need to change in the config file? The only thing I've changed is I switched 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' in the config file, however there was a lot of other options that were commented out regarding "storage features". Does anyone know what the problem is? I saw some other posts but none regarding this particular issue.

On a side note: On the home screen there's also a warning that I do not have all the extended features, and a button to find out why. When I click "find out why" it takes me to a reference page that says something along the lines of adding a particular table, but I'm not sure how to do this because I am fairly new. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to use http://www.dbninja.com .. . more elegant product.

Comment: @JonStirling Questions about commonly used programming tools are also acceptable here...all though this question could be more clearly asked.

Comment: @Mark phpMyAdmin is not a programming tool, it's a database viewer. By the same token your reasoning would make the likes of asking why MySQL workbench isn't working properly an on-topic question to ask on SO. Saying that, you're right to an extent, i.e. SQL help is on topic, but OP isn't asking for SQL help.

Comment: @JonStirling Well I know that I use PHPMyAdmin daily in my programming work, and that I even get into the guts and modify it to do what I need (though that isn't the case here, clearly).